# Show that $ f $ is infinitely differentiable function on $ \mathbb{R} \text{ and } f^{(n)}(0) = 0$

Tags: calculus

Hello can you help me with that...

Let $ f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be the function defined as follows: $ f(x) = 0 \text{ if } x \leq 0 \text{ and } f(x) = e^{- \frac{1}{x}} \text{ if } x > 0 $. Show that $ f $ is infinitely differentiable function on $ \mathbb{R} \text{ and } f^{(n)}(0) = 0 \text{ for every } n \in \mathbb{N} $

I tried to find the derivative of $ f(0) $

$ f^{'} (0) $ $= \lim_{h\to 0} $ $ \frac{e^{\frac{-1}{h}}}{h} $

$ \lim_{h \to 0^\mathtt{\text{-}}} \frac{e^{- \frac{1}{h}}}{h}=-\infty  $

$ \lim_{h \to 0^\mathtt{\text{+}}} \frac{e^{- \frac{1}{h}}}{h}=0 $

So this limit doesn't exists and this function doesn't have derivative at zero
so please tell me what's my mistake

Comment: $f(x)$ is defined to be $0$ for $x\le0$.

Comment: You only need the right limits, the left limits are all zero. See the definition of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidMitra has pointed out that $f(x) = 0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ by definition, so your left-handed limit should be zero.  Your right-handed limit is correct, so the limit is zero.